# How to calculate distance between two locations in kilometers, in php?

Tags: php, geolocation, distance

I have a table in which I am storing the service and columns of service table is lattitude, longitude i.e location of a service.

Now I want to get the current location of the user and search the services available around 10 kilometers distance to the user.

For this I searched how to calculate the distance between two locations and tried one of the code but it is giving me some syntax error in JSON.

The error is syntax error, (unexpected 'S'), also I don't get the result in kilometers by this formula.

```
     public function searchVendors($lattitudeFrom,$longitudeFrom)
    {
        $lattitudeTo = -10.4212157;
        $longitudeTo = 28.6031842;


        $dist = $this -> haversineGreatCircleDistance($latitudeFrom, $longitudeFrom, $latitudeTo, $longitudeTo, $earthRadius = 6371000);

        return $dist;

    }

 public function haversineGreatCircleDistance($latitudeFrom, $longitudeFrom, $latitudeTo, $longitudeTo, $earthRadius = 6371000)
{
    // convert from degrees to radians
    $latFrom = deg2rad($latitudeFrom);
    $lonFrom = deg2rad($longitudeFrom);
    $latTo = deg2rad($latitudeTo);
    $lonTo = deg2rad($longitudeTo);

    $latDelta = $latTo - $latFrom;
    $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;

    $angle = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin($latDelta / 2), 2) +
        cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * pow(sin($lonDelta / 2), 2)));
    return $angle * $earthRadius;
}
```

getVendors.php

```
  <?php

header("Content-type: application/json");

   // if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
        include_once ("../include/Vendor.php");
    try {

    $con = DB::getConnection();

    $raw = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $data = json_decode($raw, true);

    $longitude = $data->longitude;
    $lattitude = $data->lattitude;

    $v = new Vendor();
    $response = $v -> searchVendors($lattitude,$longitude);


    json_encode($response);


    echo $response;

        if ( $response == null ) {
            $response = json_encode(array("result" => -2, "message" => "Empty result"));
            echo $response;
        } else {
            echo $response;
        }
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $result = array("result" => -1, "message" => $e -> getMessage());
        echo json_encode($result);
        }
//}
?>
```

How can I achieve this? Can anyone help please.. Very new in php.

Comment: Can you provide the full error message with filename and line number?

Answer (score 0):

php cal_dist(a,b,key=none,spec=km)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for find distance in KM or MILES

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

      $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
      $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
      $dist = acos($dist);
      $dist = rad2deg($dist);
      $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
      $unit = strtoupper($unit);

      if ($unit == "K") {
        return ($miles * 1.609344);
      } else if ($unit == "N") {
          return ($miles * 0.8684);
        } else {
            return $miles;
          }
    }
```

Comment: tried this code, still getting the same syntax error, anything wrong in my  other code? @Rax Shah